# login button jsp form

Tags: jsp, session, authentication

```
<div class = "loginform">
    <form action = 'SPACE_HeaderLogin.jsp' id='form_login' >
        <div class ='row'>
        <div class = 'form-group'>
            <label  class = 'control-label col-xs-2 col-md-offset-3 col-md-2' for='id_username'></label>
              <div class = 'col-xs-3 col-md-2'><input type='text' name = "username" id='id_username' placeholder='Enter your LoginID' class = 'form-control'></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <br> 
        <div class ='row'>
        <div class = 'form-group'>
            <label class = 'control-label col-xs-2 col-md-offset-3 col-md-2' for='id_password'></label>
            <div class = 'col-xs-3 col-md-2'><input type='password' name = 'password' id='id_password' placeholder = 'Enter your password' class = 'form-control'></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <br> <br>
        <input type="submit" name = "login" id ="login" value="Login" id="login_button" class= "btn btn-primary col-md-offset-5 col-xs-offset-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2">
            <% if(request.getParameter("login")!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("hi");
                    SPACE_GetLoginDetails space_loginDetails = new SPACE_GetLoginDetails();
                    SPACE_LoginModel space_loginModel = new SPACE_LoginModel();
                    space_loginModel = space_loginDetails.SPACE_getLoginDetails(request.getParameter("username"));
                    session.setAttribute("prioritylevel", space_loginModel.getSPLD_PriorityLevel());
                }   
                    %>
    </form>
    </div>
    <%@include file="SPACE_Footer.jsp" %>
    <%= generate_footer()%>
```

This is my login.jsp page. When I hit the login button , it is supposed to validate the if condition and perform the code inside. But it is not.  In SPACE_HeaderLogin.jsp I need to get the session parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> When I hit the login button , it is supposed to validate the if condition and perform the code inside

You are wrong here. When you hit the login button, the browser is only supposed to get all the input fields and send a new request to `SPACE_HeaderLogin.jsp`. The scriptlet code (`<% ... %>`) has been executed on the server when the login.jsp was executed to prepare the page sent to the browser. Said differently here is the timeline:

- the browser send a request for login.jsp
- the server (eventually compiles and) execute the login.jsp to generate a page and send it back to the browser - **the scriptlets are executed at that moment**
- the browser receives and displays the login.jsp page
- the user fills the input fields and clicks on a submit button
- the browsers uses the input fields to prepare a new request and sends it to the server for SPACE_HeaderLogin.jsp

If you want code to be executed when the user clicks on a button, the code can only be client side javascript that has no direct access to the server session.

IMHO the best way to do what you want is to make the form to hit a Servlet that will process the parameters and then forward to the second jsp